# Akka dead letters encountered

Tags: java, akka

I have `MainActor` which inside constructor initializes two child `SubActorA` and `SubActorB`.

```
SubActorA= this.getContext().actorOf(Props.create(SubActorA.class), "SubActorA");
SubActorB= this.getContext().actorOf(Props.create(SubActorB.class), "SubActorB");

public class SubActorA extends UntypedActor {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object o) throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        getSender().tell(new MessageResponseA().events + System.currentTimeMillis(), getSelf());
        getContext().stop(getSelf());
    }
}

public class SubActorB extends UntypedActor {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object o) throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        getSender().tell(new MessageResponseB().events + System.currentTimeMillis(), getSelf());
        getContext().stop(getSelf());
    }
}
```

`MainActor` receives a `Message` request from outside actors world:

```
public Future<Iterable<Object>> start(){

    final ArrayList<Future<Object>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
    Timeout t = new Timeout(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    futures.add(ask(this.mainActor, new Message(customerCookie), t));
    final Future<Iterable<Object>> aggregate = Futures.sequence(futures,
            system.dispatcher());

    return aggregate;
}
```

As soon as `MainActor` received `Message` it sends it to two its childs `SubActorA` and `SubActorB`.

```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
        if(message instanceof `Message`){
            generalPersonalisationSender = getSender();
            SubActorA.tell(new MessageA(customerCookie), getSelf());
            SubActorB.tell(new MessageB(customerCookie), getSelf());
        }
        else if(message instanceof `MessageResponseA`){
            listener.tell(message, getSelf())
        }
        else if(message instanceof `MessageResponseB`){
            listener.tell(message, getSelf())
        }
}
```

So you can see that two messages has been sent to each of sub actors. But unfortunately I am getting only one message back and aslo `INFO` notification about `DeadLetter`. `Message was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered.`

Could you please help me to find why i am not getting 2nd message? is it something to do with shutting down an actor, but I stop it only on lowest inside `Subactors`.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you post the code of the two subactors? Also, I assume you are not getting the B message, right? Which message is sent to DeadLetters (the one from main to a, main to b, a to main or b to main)?

Comment: @DiegoMartinoia, I have added SubActors. DeadLetters occurs on the path from MainActor to any other actor I am returning a result.

Comment: One immediate potential problem I can see is that you are (probably) not sending a MessageResponseX from neither A or B to the main one: you are sending a MessageResponseX.events+Long . According to however the + operator works on your events, you are probably sending either a Long, a String or a collection of Long/Object

Comment: @DiegoMartinoia, thanks thats correct! Can I ask you few more questions in the chat? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74818/akka

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are not actually returning a MessageResponseX from neither A or B to the main one: you are sending a MessageResponseX.events+Long . According to however the + operator works on your events, you are probably sending either a Long, a String or a collection of Long/Object.

Therefore, your MainActor receive method is not intercepting it, and it goes to DeadLetters.